# Problem when I download things

Tags: xfce, wget

I have a chromebook with ubuntu xfce. I'm trying to download an auto clicker. I typed

```
$ cd ~/Downloads && wget -c http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/64-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick‌​64Bit.zip
```

in the terminal and it worked but when I went into folders and downloads and clicked it, it said: `Failed to open file` Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you've got the wrong link.
The file which actually contains the application is this one:
[Just download it using your browser.](http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/64-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick64Bit.zip) Then navigate to the directory where the file is located, right click it and unzip it.
I guess some kind of executeable will get unpacked.

Greetings, Didi

Comment: I downloaded it but when i extract it, it says "Could not open archive Mime-type unsupported or file did not exist"

Comment: @JoeCook may [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422386/why-am-i-not-able-to-open-or-extract-zip-files-how-can-i-fix-this) help you

Comment: @c0rp when i open the files it opens in "squeeze"

Comment: @JoeCook The archive at http://www.murguu.com/linux-auto-mouse-click/download/64-bit/LinuxAutoMouseClick64Bit.zip is valid.

Comment: @Oli i got it had to use the terminal to unzip the file, but when i extracted it it opens something called "squeeze" no clue what that is

Comment: @JoeCook How are you extracting it? If you're doing it from the command line, `tar` won't work. You need `unzip`.

Comment: @Oli i unzipped it